# detox - assembleAndroidTest Error

Tags: react-native, e2e-testing, detox, lottie

I am using Detox and iOS runs normally,

Android is getting an error when you type the following command. From Lottie-react-natve
"cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType = debug && cd .."

"lottie-react-native": You are using "2.5.0".

If you have any symptoms, please let me know.

I followed the guide, but I do not know what was missing.

Ps. https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/Introduction.Android.md

```
> Task :lottie-react-native:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebugAndroidTest FAILED
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /Users/bart/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/lottie-2.5.6.aar/07f7d126fc996117a3a317ef18e9483d/jars/classes.jar
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)
        at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:146)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.transform(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:308)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor336.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:623)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:578)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /Users/bart/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/lottie-2.5.6.aar/07f7d126fc996117a3a317ef18e9483d/jars/classes.jar
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:805)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.lambda$convertToDexArchive$8(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:730)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
The dependency contains Java 8 bytecode. Please enable desugaring by adding the following to build.gradle
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
}
See https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html for details. Alternatively, increase the minSdkVersion to 26 or above.

        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:175)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:152)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:800)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:76)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:45)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:88)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:147)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:77)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:67)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:62)
        ... 10 more
        Suppressed: com.android.tools.r8.ApiLevelException: Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)
                at com.android.tools.r8.dex.FileWriter.checkThatInvokeCustomIsAllowed(FileWriter.java:1296)
                at com.android.tools.r8.dex.FileWriter.writeCallSite(FileWriter.java:635)
                at com.android.tools.r8.dex.FileWriter.writeFixedSectionItems(FileWriter.java:302)
                at com.android.tools.r8.dex.FileWriter.generate(FileWriter.java:193)
                at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationWriter.writeDexFile(ApplicationWriter.java:356)
                at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationWriter.lambda$write$2(ApplicationWriter.java:188)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
                Suppressed: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.r8.ApiLevelException: Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)
                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
                        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ThreadUtils.awaitFutures(ThreadUtils.java:21)
                        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationWriter.write(ApplicationWriter.java:216)
                        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:167)
                        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.lambda$run$1(D8.java:91)
                        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:58)
                        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:45)
                        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:88)
                        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:147)
                        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:800)
                        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.lambda$convertToDexArchive$8(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:730)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
        [CIRCULAR REFERENCE:com.android.tools.r8.ApiLevelException: Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)]



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':lottie-react-native:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /Users/bart/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/lottie-2.5.6.aar/07f7d126fc996117a3a317ef18e9483d/jars/classes.jar
```

Comment: I had similar issue with another sdk. I used `./gradlew assembleAndroidTest -x [failingTaskName]` in my gradle task. Because this is an assemble job for testApk, I didn't see the need of packaging dependencies declared for application.

Comment: @vk.4884 Thanks. I'll try it the way you told me, by the way What does mean fallingTaskName?

Comment: In your case the failingTask is `:lottie-react-native:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebugAndroidTest`.

Comment: @vk.4884 Thank. :)